# Problem implementing openUrl function in recycler view adapter

Tags: java, android, kotlin, url, android-recyclerview

I wanted to openUrl when someone clicked on the title in the recyclerview, but it showing an error for startActivity(intent).

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ItemHolder, position: Int) {

        val itemModel: ItemModel = arrayList[position]

        holder.title.text = itemModel.title
        holder.source.text = itemModel.source
        val url = itemModel.url

        holder.title.setOnClickListener {
            Toast.makeText(context, itemModel.title, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

            val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
            intent.data = Uri.parse(url)
            intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
            startActivity(intent)
        }

    }
```

Comment: Where's the error (log)

Comment: Try change `startActivity(intent)` -> `holder.itemView.context.startActivity(intent)`